# Add Encodable extension to Swift nested enum

Tags: swift, enums, codable, encodable

I want to encode instances of the existing `NWInterface` class which has a `type` field of type `NWInterface.InterfaceType` which is an `enum`.

Is there a way to easily add the `Encodable` interface to that nested type?  At the moment my workaround is to handle the encoding in an extension to the enclosing class:

```
extension NWInterface : Encodable {

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case type
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        switch type {
            case .wifi:
                try container.encode("wifi", forKey: .type)
            case .cellular:
                try container.encode("cellular", forKey: .type)
            case .wiredEthernet:
                try container.encode("ethernet", forKey: .type)
            case .loopback:
                try container.encode("loopback", forKey: .type)
            case .other:
                try container.encode("other", forKey: .type)
            default:
                try container.encode("unknown", forKey: .type)
        }
    }
}
```

This feels *unsatisfactory*, especially since for my own defined `enum` types I can simply add the `Encodable` interface at the point of definition and get the implementation "for free".

Comment: The compiler can (iirc) only synthesise automatic `Codable` conformance within a struct's original file, so you will have to explicitly define the encoder/decoder to achieve conformance.

Comment: @flanker indeed, and doing that latter is what I'm trying to find a clean approach for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a `Encodable` conformance to a nested enum?

Yes

Do you get it for free, like with your own enums?

No. I don't know why, but automatic `Codable` synthesis seems to require that the extension be in the same file as the `struct`, `class` or `enum`.

Here's what the implementation extending the nested `enum` would look like.

```swift
extension NWInterface : Encodable {
    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case name, type
    }
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
    }
}

extension NWInterface.InterfaceType : Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
            case .wifi:
                try container.encode("wifi")
            case .cellular:
                try container.encode("cellular")
            case .wiredEthernet:
                try container.encode("ethernet")
            case .loopback:
                try container.encode("loopback")
            case .other:
                try container.encode("other")
            default:
                try container.encode("unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

You could also squeeze the second extension down to:

```swift
extension NWInterface.InterfaceType : Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode("\(self)")
    }
}
```

provided you take appropriate measures to handle unexpected strings in your `Decoder`.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  It was the concept of the `singleValueContainer` that I hadn't found before.

Comment: btw, I went with the escaped string method - there's no `Decoder` for this data.

Comment: You can also add an extension to the nested `enum` and make it conform to `RawRepresentable` , which automagically is `Codable`; but it ends up being more code than the string interpolation method. It may be a win if you needed a decoder (I know you don't in this case).

Comment: Another option for the 2nd part is `try container.encode(String(describing: self)` which *feels* (although probably isn't) a bit more precise in that you get `Network.NWInterface.InterfaceType.loopback` as derived from the struct rather than `loopback`, although you still have to handle each option explicitly in the decoder.

Comment: @flanker the short name is all I need, but I would for purity's sake prefer something that doesn't rely on string interpolation to automagically convert the enum into its cases' names.

Comment: @flanker `String.init(describing: self)` gives me what I needed